# Time-Bound Query In SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, payment-gateway

I am working on a project where one of the parts processes the payment and if payment is successful, it sets a flag into the database. Now, what I want to achieve is that I have to keep querying into the database for that particular flag every second or every two seconds for 30 seconds. If I don't see that flag into the database after 30 seconds, I would say to the user that payment was unsuccessful. How do I achieve this time-bound querying? I mean how do i keep running a particular query for 30 seconds?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you should do this from your application side rather than from the SQL Server side

Comment: The database itself cannot help you here you need to realize it with some code for example PHP or whatever the language is you are using to create your shop. Just setup a while loop in your preffered language with a timeout of 1, better 2 seconds and fire another query onto your  database and make a total count of 30 seconds to exit the loop with "break" and inform the user about the failed payment. ?

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @CurrentTime datetime
SET @CurrentTime=GETDATE()
WHILE DATEDIFF(ss,@CurrentTime,GETDATE())<31
BEGIN
<Your Code Here>
END
```

You might want to also use `WAITFOR DELAY` in your code to execute once every 1 or 2 seconds

Answer (score 0):

you can use waitfordelay in a loop checking for status change.

```
   declare @flag int = 0

   select @flag = flag from MyTable with (nolock) 
   declare @i int =0

   while @flag <> 0 and @i <30
   begin

      WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01'
      select @flag = flag from MyTable with (nolock) 
      set @i = @i +1 
   end
```

Comment: please add some explaination to your answer posted, this will help others to understand it quickly.